# martingale proposition-more lated to conditional expectation-looking for details operations

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, proof-explanation, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})=([0,1),\mathscr{B}([0,1)),\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure. For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, define $$\mathcal{D}_k= \Bigg\{\Bigg[\frac{i}{2^k},\frac{i+1}{2^k}\Bigg):i=0,1,2...2^k-1 \Bigg\}\qquad\mathscr{F}_k:=\sigma(\mathcal{D_k})$$

For $f\in L^2([0,1])$,define $M_k(f):=E(f|\mathscr{F}_k)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$

For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $M_k(f)$ can be expressed as
$$\large{M_k(f)=\sum^{2^k-1}_{i=0}\mathbf{1}_{[\frac{i}{2^k},\frac{i+1}{2^k})}2^k\int^{\frac{i+1}{2^k}}_{\frac{i}{2^k}}f(s)ds}\tag{1}$$

---

**Question 1**  I can see this equation is similar to the definition of conditional expectation condition on sigma algebra, which is $$E(X|\sigma(A))=\sum^{n}_{i=0}\frac{E(X\mathbf{1}_{A_i})}{\mathbb{P}(A_i)}\mathbf{1}_{A_i}\qquad\text{where $\{A_i\}$ partition $\sigma(A)$}$$ I am consued where is that $2^k$ comes from? and why is that $2^k$ will analogues to $\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A_i)}$? Why it is $ds$ rather than $d\lambda$?

**Question 2** My professor gives proof about this, and there is a step I do not understand, I am looking for concrete operation and how it goes with it.

$$\large{\int_{I^k_j}\Bigg(\sum^{2^k-1}_{i=0}\mathbf{1}_{[\frac{i}{2^k},\frac{i+1}{2^k})}2^k\int^{\frac{i+1}{2^k}}_{\frac{i}{2^k}}f(s)ds\Bigg)dx=\color{red}{\int_{I^k_j}2^k\int_{I^k_j}f(s)dsdx=\int_{I^k_j}f(s)ds}}$$

I would like to know how does equality happen in the red part.

**Question 3** $$\large{M_k(f)(t)=\frac{1}{|I_t|}\int_{I_t}f(s)ds}\tag{2}$$ This is equivalent to **(1)**, from the definition $E(X|A)$ I can sort of get it, but I have no idea about how exactstep from equation (1) to this one.

genuinely thank you for your help.

Comment: $2^k = 1/(2^{-k})$.

Comment: $ds$ means the same as $d\lambda(s)$.

Comment: The proof is the formula you wrote. The formula is not a definition, it is a theorem.

Comment: @Mason Thank you for your reply. The formula you mean $E(X|\sigma(A))$? In some books,(Jia-an Yan-introduction to stochastic finance) it is call defined as. Would you please elaborate the red part?

Comment: The whole thing you wrote in question 2 is the same as proving in your question 1 that $E(E(X \mid \sigma(A))1_{A_i}) = E(X1_{A_i})$.

Comment: @Mason Yeah, for the general idea I could get it, but I would like to know the details step how $2^k$ disappears. From general idea, I could get $\int_A E(X|\sigma(A))d\mathbb{P}=\int_AXd\mathbb{P}=$

Comment: You must not understand your formula in Q1, because the computation and formula in question 2 are a special case of the formula in Q1. The $2^k$ disappears because $\lambda(I_{j}^k) = 2^{-k}$.

Comment: @Mason Thank you for your reply. What you wrote makes me retrieve the lebesgue integral of the simple function, however, it raised me another question in the form $\int_A Xd\mathbb{P}=E(X\mathbf{1}_A)$ why doesn't this not in form of something related to $\mathbb{P}(A)$?

Comment: @Mason Sorry for bothering you again. Would you please check out his question by any chance? Genuinely thank you for your patience https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525262/why-wouldnt-int-a-jxd-mathbbp-in-form-related-to-mathbbpa-j