# Why wouldn't $\int_{A_j}Xd\mathbb{P}$ in form related to$\mathbb{P}(A_j)$

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

I know that $$\int_{A_j}E(X|\sigma(A))d\mathbb{P}=\int_{A_j}\Big(\sum_i^n\frac{\mathbf{1}_{A_i}}{\mathbb{P}(A_i)}\int_{A_i}Xd\mathbb{P}\Big)d\mathbb{P}\\=
\int_{A_j}\Big(\sum_{i\neq j}^n\frac{\mathbf{1}_{A_{i}}}{\mathbb{P}(A_{i})}\int_{A_{i}}Xd\mathbb{P}\Big)d\mathbb{P}+\int_{A_j}\Big(\frac{\mathbf{1}_{A_j}}{\mathbb{P}(A_j)}\int_{A_j}Xd\mathbb{P}\Big)d\mathbb{P}\\
=\int_{A_j}\Big(\sum_{i\neq j}^n\frac{\mathbf{1}_{A_{i}}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{A_j}}{\mathbb{P}(A_{i})}\int_{A_{i}}Xd\mathbb{P}\Big)d\mathbb{P}+\color{red}{\int_{A_j}\Big(\frac{\mathbf{1}_{A_j}}{\mathbb{P}(A_j)}\int_{A_j}Xd\mathbb{P}\Big)d\mathbb{P}}\\
=\sum_{i\neq j}^n\frac{\mathbb{P}({A_{i}}\cap{A_j})=0}{\mathbb{P}(A_{i})}\int_{A_{i}}Xd\mathbb{P}+\color{red}{\Big(\frac{\mathbb{P}(A_j)}{\mathbb{P}(A_j)}\int_{A_j}Xd\mathbb{P}\Big)}\\=\int_{A_j}Xd\mathbb{P}$$

Where $\{A_i\}$ partition the sample space.

From previous step we could see it has used the integral of simple function $\int\mathbf{1}_{A_j}d\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{P}(A_j)$. My question is why doesn't $\int_{A_j}Xd\mathbb{P}$ will be some form related to $\mathbb{P}(A_j)$, but rather $E(X\mathbf{1}_{A_j})$, even though it's part of definition, is it possible to be other form?

Comment: @AlvinL Thank you for your reply. I meant taking sum over $n$ over without $j$ I possible should remove $n$ at the top. I was trying to emphasise $i\neq j$ at each step. Would you please enlighten me a bit on the question?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now what's going on. I don't know how $\int _A Xd\mathbb P$ could be related to $\mathbb P(A)$ in general, though.

Comment: @AlvinL My question can be like： why does the red part, integral operate on $\mathbf{1}_{A_j}$ having output $\mathbb{P}(A_j)$, whereas $\int X\mathbf{1}_{A_j}d\mathbb{P}$ is not?

Comment: $\int \mathbf{1}_{A} d\mathbb{P} =\mathbb{E}\mathbf{1}_{A}=\mathbb{P}(A)$

Comment: @Tobsn Thank you for your reply. I meant $\int_AXd\mathbb{P}$, why doesn't this in form of something related to $\mathbb{P}(A)$, in contrast to the first red equation, that integral will have $\mathbb{P}(A)$